# Android Image to View in Full Screen

Tags: android, gridview, fullscreen, bitmapimage

I'm new to Android and Java. I have been working on my task i.e, Image Downloader. Where I have to download images with progress bar and display them in grid View. I have created two classes 1. URLImageAdapter 2. CacheActivity. **Everything works fine but now I want these images to open in full screen when clicked** Any help? thank You.
Any Simple Method.

```
public class URLImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private File sdImageMainDirectory;
private Context myContext;
private class Image {
    String url;
    Bitmap thumb;
}

private Image[] images;
private LoadThumbsTask thumbnailGen;
private Object previousList;

public URLImageAdapter(Context c) {
    myContext = c;
    thumbnailGen = new LoadThumbsTask();

    if (previousList != null) {
        images = (Image[]) previousList;
        thumbnailGen.execute(images);
        return;
    }

    images = new Image[imageURLs.length];

    for (int i = 0, j = imageURLs.length; i < j; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].url = imageURLs[i];

    }

    thumbnailGen.execute(images);

}

private void saveDataInSdCard(Bitmap bt,int i) {
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    Uri outputFileUri;
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "urFlodername" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root,i+"myPicName.jpg");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Bitmap bm =bt;
    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }       

}

public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position].url;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Object getData() {
    if (thumbnailGen != null
            && thumbnailGen.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        thumbnailGen.cancel(true);
    }

    return images;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgView;

    Image cached = images[position];

    if (convertView == null) {

        imgView = new ImageView(myContext);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

    } else {

        imgView = (ImageView) convertView;

    }

    if (cached.thumb == null) {

        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

    } else {

        imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(cached.thumb);
        saveDataInSdCard(cached.thumb,position);

    }

    return imgView;
}

private void cacheUpdated() {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private Bitmap loadThumb(String url) {

    Bitmap thumb = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = 4;

    try {

        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        c.connect();

        BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(
                c.getInputStream());

        thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, opts);


        stream.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "malformed url: " + url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "An error has occurred downloading the image: "
                + url);
    }

    return thumb;
}

private class LoadThumbsTask extends AsyncTask<Image, Void, Void> {

    /*private ProgressDialog dialog;
      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myContext, "Please wait",
            "Downloading.....", true);
                }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    //Intent for next activity
     this.dialog.dismiss();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Image... cache) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = 4;

        for (Image i : cache) {

            if (isCancelled())
                return null;

            if (i.thumb != null)
                continue;

            SystemClock.sleep(500);

            i.thumb = loadThumb(i.url);

            publishProgress();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... param) {
        cacheUpdated();
    }
}

private String[] imageURLs = {
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2851.jpg",
                   "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2944.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2989.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3005.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3012.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3034.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3047.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3092.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3110.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3113.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3128.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3160.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3226.jpg",
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3228.jpg",};
 }
```

> CacheActivity

```
public class CacheActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStartProgress;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
private GridView gridview;
private long fileSize = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cache);
     gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
     addListenerOnButton();
}




public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.show();

            progressBarStatus = 0;

            fileSize = 0;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                        progressBarStatus = doInBackground();


                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(7500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(450);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        progressBar.dismiss();

                    }
                }
            }).start();
            try {
                gridview.setAdapter(new URLImageAdapter(CacheActivity.this));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

}

public int doInBackground() {

    while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

        fileSize++;

        if (fileSize == 100000) {
            return 10;
        } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
            return 20;
        } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
            return 30;
        }else if (fileSize == 400000) {
            return 40;
        }else if (fileSize == 500000) {
            return 50;
        }else if (fileSize == 600000) {
            return 60;
        }else if (fileSize == 700000) {
            return 70;
        }else if (fileSize == 800000) {
            return 80;
        }else if (fileSize == 900000) {
            return 90;
        }

    }

    return 100;

}

}
```

Comment: @njzk2 Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context,1); dialog.setContentView(your layout); dialog.show();

Want to start a fresh but thinking of trying this.

Comment: that would do. an overlay view (like in a relative layout or something) that stays hidden and becomes visible can work too.

Comment: @njzk2 Can you suggest me anything else?

Comment: use a relative layout with your listView and an imageview on top of each other (image on top). define the image as gone, and make it visible when needed, puting your selected image in it

Comment: @njzk2 I'm jus new to android :(

Please be specific and submit your answer
Will be great if Helped.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

set onClickListener to your imageView in getView when it get thumb image.

```
   else {

            imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(cached.thumb);
            saveDataInSdCard(cached.thumb,position);

           //somewhat here

           // and start a new activity and put file path , and your next activity there is       

            imgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener())
              {

                @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent =new Intent(context,FullScreenActivity.class)
                  intent.putExtra("file_path",PATH);
                  context.startActivity(intent);
                 } 

               });


        }
```

And in your next activity there is a full screen imageView

in onCreate

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle!=null)
{
String path=bundle.getString("file_path");
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
}
```

Comment: Bro I will send you the code can u edit for me?
I tried but some exceptions.!! Please

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I asked him not U.
I guess U hav much better work than these lame comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom alert dialog imageview with full size imageview.get image from grid view and display it in alert dialog.